# Fading in PHP post return data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein

This is my current jQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function() { 
    var texts = $('#texts').val();
    var calls = $('#calls').val();
    var callstometeor = $('#callstometeor').val();
    $.post('compare.php', { texts: texts, calls: calls, callstometeor: callstometeor }, function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
} );
} );
```

And this is the HTML div:

```
<p><div id="result"></div></p>
```

How would I get the data that is returned back from the PHP file but instead of just displaying it, make it fade in with jQuery. Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm a bit of a noob at jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

This one does it. It hides #result div first, fills it with response data and fades in

```
$('#result').hide().html(data).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() { 
    var texts = $('#texts').val();
    var calls = $('#calls').val();
    var callstometeor = $('#callstometeor').val();
    $.post('compare.php', { texts: texts, calls: calls, callstometeor: callstometeor }, function(data) {
    var res= data; //here you get the response
    alert(res);
    $('#result').hide().html(data).fadeIn();
});
});
});
```